# Trim String value with particular pattern in C#.NET

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a string which is 900-1000 characters long.
the pattern string follows is

> "Number:something,somestringNumber:something,somestring"

and so on example string:

> "23:value,ordernew14:valueagain,orderagain"

the requirement is whenever it crosses more than 1000 characters, I have to remove first 500 characters. and then if doesnot starts with Number, i have to remove characters until I reach to point where first character is digit

```
sortinfo = sortinfo.Remove(0, 500);
sortinfo = new string(sortinfo.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

I am able to do this with the help of above code

In the above example if i give remove 5 characters output will be

> 14:valueagain,orderagain

which is perfectly fine.
but if the string has value :

> 23:value,or3dernew14:valueagain,orderagain

and remove 5 characters, output is

> 3dernew14:valueagain,orderagain

and requirement is to have

> 14:valueagain,orderagain

and hence its breaking everything as it is not in correct format.
please help me how can I do this

my full code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;
        str=TrimSortInfo("23:value,ord4er24:valueag4ain,order6again15:value,order"); // breaking value
        //str = TrimSortInfo("23:value,order24:valueagain,orderagain15:value,order"); //working value
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static string TrimSortInfo(string sortinfo)
    {
        if (sortinfo.Length > 15)
        {
            sortinfo = sortinfo.Remove(0, 15);
            sortinfo = new string(sortinfo.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c))
                         .ToArray());
            return sortinfo;
        }
        return sortinfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try regex for above solution?

Comment: You want to go to the next "pattern"... but your pattern is very poor, because you don't have a real separator between records... So now you have a problem.

Comment: is number always going to be like this `14:`? if yes you can match for number for pattern like `14:` else continue

Comment: yes thats the problem pattern is very poor and hence facing the issue, can't change the pattern, its existing from years and many things are dependent on it, changing it will break lots of stuffs. have to work in the same pattern :(

Comment: @Prashant you didnt answer my question

Comment: number can be anything but it will always follows by colon

Comment: I think he meant if it's always followed by a `:`. Since then you could do a regex like `\d+:` to match your start

Comment: Freggar just answered your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex("(?<=.*?)[0-9]+:.*");

static string TrimSortInfo(string sortinfo, int trimLength = 15)
{
    if (sortinfo.Length > trimLength)
    {
        return rx.Match(sortinfo, trimLength).Value;
    }
    return sortinfo;
}
```

Note that there is a big risk here: you could trim "in the middle" of the number.

So you could trim a "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx24:something" to "4:something".

The regex means: looking for a sequence of digits 0-9 (at least one digit) (`[0-9]+`), followed by a `:`, followed by all the other characters (`.*`). Before this sequence there can be any other character, but only the minimum quantity possible `(?<=.*?)`. This pre-sequence isn't captured `(?<=...)`.

In the end the regex can be simplified to:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex("[0-9]+:.*");
```

because it is unanchored, so the match will begin at the first occurrence of the match.

To solve this problem:

```
static Regex rx = new Regex("(?:[^0-9])([0-9]+:.*)");

static string TrimSortInfo(string sortinfo, int trimLength = 15)
{
    if (sortinfo.Length > trimLength)
    {
        return rx.Match(sortinfo, trimLength - 1).Groups[1].Value;
    }
    return sortinfo;
}
```

We cheat a little. To trim 15 characters, we skip 14 characters (`trimLength - 1`) then we capture a non-digit character (that we will ignore `(?:[^0-9])`) plus the digits and the : and everything else `([0-9]+:.*)`. Note the use of `Groups[1].Value`

Comment: To address that last point, first remove 499 chars and ensure that you remove at least 1 non-digit.

Comment: @bommelding And if you are removing a digit what would you do? You would need to skip twice...

Comment: Yes, if you hit a digit then you first have to skip that and all other digits and a `:` if it is present. And from that  point on apply your regex.

Comment: @bommelding Changed the regex... it is easier than I thought.

Comment: ah it risky, i Tried different possibilities and it failed for 
23:value,ord4e24:valueag4ain,order6again15:value,order
breaking not the patter is very important, i cant miss even a single digit from pattern. Either i need to keep full pattern or remove that one completely
number 24 appears only as 4 in output :(

Comment: @Prashant The last version of code solves this problem

Comment: @xanatos Can you explain whats does Groups[1].Value does? it did a magic

Comment: @Prashant I skip 14 instead of 15, to check that the 15th isn't a digit. So the 15th is captured by `(?:[^0-9])`... But I'm not interested in that. I only want to check that it isn't a digit and skip it. The part that I'm interested of the match is the `([0-9]+:.*)`, that being in `()` is automatically made the group 1 by Regex. So I `Group[1].Value`